# Incorporate geckoFx with tabControl

Tags: winforms, tabcontrol, geckofx

I have 2 windows forms.

- TabControl.cs which has a tabControl.
- Browser.cs which has a geckoBrowser inside.

Browser.cs works, i cant succesfully display a website inside the geckoFx browser.

I want to create a new tab and load the Browser.cs inside, when i am setting the properties of the tab i am getting error saying i am missing some geckoFiles.

I dont understand why since Browser.cs works.

Here is the code.

**Browser**

```
 public partial class Browser: Form
{
    public Browser()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Browser_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      geckoWebBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.google.com");
    }
}
```

}

**TabControl**

```
private void createTab()
        {
            TabPage newTab= new TabPage();
            Browser browser= new Browser();
            browser.MdiParent = this;
            browser.TopLevel = false;
            browser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            browser.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(3, 3);
            browser.Show();
            newtab.Controls.Add(browser);
            tabControl1.TabPages.Add(newTab);
            tabControl1.SelectedTab = newTab;


        }

    private void tabControl_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        createTab();
    }
```

**Program.cs**

```
  static void Main()
    {
        var path = System.IO.Path.Combine(
        Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "xulrunner");
        Gecko.Xpcom.Initialize(path); 
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new tabControl());
    }
```

*Note: I am using geckofx and xlrunner version 29*

The createTab method raises some exceptions of missing files.

1. **browser.MdiParent = this;**
   *Unable to find Xpcom.cs*
2. *Unable to find GeckoWebBrowser.WinForms.cs*

Answer (score 0):

The reason for your first exception

> 1. Unable to find Xpcom.cs

is that you haven't called `Xpcom.Initialize(path);` with a valid path to correct firefox/xulrunner dll's.